# Delete every seventh line using sed

Tags: sed

I need a sed script that deletes every seventh line in a file. I managed to do this with an awk script but wanted to look for a way to use sed to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
sed 'n;n;n;n;n;n;d;'
```

Answer (score 4):

Sai solution seems to be the best one. However, if you are using GNU sed and does not look for portability, you can use the step address:

```
$ seq 1 10 | sed '0~3d'
1
2
4
5
7
8
10
```

The `n~m` address matches all k-th line where k = n+m*i.